# How to convert integer value to char? Scheme, DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to convert integer to char. I read doc files, but didn't find any information about suitable function. I found only these function 
(char->integer char), but it returns a character’s code-point number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number can be converted to a string:

```
(number->string #b1010) ; ==> "10"
```

It takes an optional base (integers don't have base, but the representation does)

```
(number->string #b1010 2) ; ==> "1010"
```

For it to be one char it had to be below the base. You can always turn a string into a list of characters with `string->list`.